# angular.js:11706 TypeError: $q.resolve is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I am beginner to the angularjs and learning it form one course on plural sight . During learning i was developing the small application . But i am getting error as below and not able to trace it . Please help .

**Error :**

```
angular.js:11706 TypeError: $q.resolve is not a function
    at commitRoute (angular-route.js:716)
    at Scope.$broadcast (angular.js:14889)
    at afterLocationChange (angular.js:11550)
    at angular.js:11536
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14570)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14386)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14675)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1458)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4219)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1456)
```

**Application Code :**

**app.js**

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module("githubViewer", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when("/main", {
    templateUrl: "main.html",
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/main"
  });

});

}());
```

**github.js**

```
var github = function($http) {

 var getUser = function(username) {
  return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
 };


var getRepos = function(user) {
  return $http.get(user.repos_url)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
};

return { 

  getUser: getUser,
  getRepos: getRepos

};

};

var module = angular.module('githubViewer');

module.factory("github", github);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="githubViewer">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<script>
document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" 
src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20">
</script>
<script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.6.2" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-
route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="MainController.js"></script>
 <script src="github.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Github Viewer</h1>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.html**

```
<div>
    <form name="searchUserForm">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Enter user to find" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

**MainController.js**

```
var app = angular.module("githubViewer");
app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
$scope.searchUser = function(username) {
  //pl
};
});
```

**UserDetails.js**

```
 var app = angular.module('githubViewer');

    app.controller('UserController', function($scope, $http,github) {

    var onUserComplete = function(data) {
    $scope.user = data;
    github.getRepos($scope.user).then(onRepos, onError);
    };

    var onRepos = function(data){
    $scope.repos = data;
    }


    $scope.username = 'angular';
    $scope.repoSortedOrder ='-stargazers_count';

    var onError = function(reason) {
    $scope.error = "Could not fetch the data";
    }

    $scope.searchUser = function(username) {
      github.getUser(username).then(onUserComplete, onError);
    };

    });
```

Please help with the above.

Comment: Please add the error message to your question, otherwise it will be hard to answer...

Comment: angular.js:11706 TypeError: $q.resolve is not a function
    at commitRoute (angular-route.js:716)
    at Scope.$broadcast (angular.js:14889)
    at afterLocationChange (angular.js:11550)
    at angular.js:11536
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14570)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14386)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14675)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1458)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4219)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1456)

Comment: Have you included angular-route.js to your html?

Comment: What angularjs version do you use?

Comment: Yes, you can see in index.html angular-route.js is included

Comment: It is 1.3.20/angular.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the same tutorial, I had the same error. I solved it by making sure that the routing module is exactly the same as the one in that tutorial (`<script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular-route.js"></script>`), there is a possibility that the one you have is a later version. This should work.